# Problems after changing SSH port

Tags: centos, ssh

I'm trying to SSH into a CentOS7 server using a specific port.
The following rules are the iptables rules:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

**Allow appropriate ports IN, OUT and FORWARD**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2113 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 168.63.129.16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 168.63.129.16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 172.16.13.4 --sport 3389 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.16.13.4 --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
```

**Allow RDP to az-ws**

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.16.13.4 --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 172.16.13.4 --sport 3389 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2113 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.13.4:3389
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**Allow SSH to az-ls**

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.16.13.5 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.16.13.5 --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

SELinux is set to enforced, however, the policy is updated and is listening and allowing on port 2113

sshd_config is setup currently to listen on two ports, port 2113 and port 22.

If I remove port 22 from sshd_conf, I can not ssh in and if I try to specify port 2113 I either get a connection time out error or ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset error. I'm not sure how to solve this problem

Comment: You have a DNAT rule that redirects port 2113 traffic to 172.16.13.4:3389. 3389 is the Windows RDP port. Could that be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2113 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.13.4:3389
```

You say you configured sshd to listen on port 2113 but you have diverted all that traffic to some other host. Thus sshd can never be reached.

You need to choose a different port, or remove the diversion.